# huge data export in pdf itextsharp

Tags: vb.net, pdf, itext, export-to-pdf

I try to export data in PDF there is huge data so when i export ..here i dont export data from gridview but actually here i create dummy gridview in code and bind data in that grid.. i am not displaying the data the grid in page .. I try below code

```
    Private Sub ExportGridToPDF()
        Using myMemoryStream As New MemoryStream()

            Dim myDocument As New iTextSharp.text.Document(iTextSharp.text.PageSize.A1, 10.0F, 10.0F, 10.0F, 0.0F)
            ' Dim myDocument As New iTextSharp.text.Document()
            Dim myPDFWriter As PdfWriter = PdfWriter.GetInstance(myDocument, myMemoryStream)

            myDocument.Open()

            ' Add to content to your PDF here...

            Dim sw As New StringWriter()
            Dim hw As New HtmlTextWriter(sw)
            GridView1.AllowPaging = False
            GridView1.DataBind()
            GridView1.RenderControl(hw)
            ' We're done adding stuff to our PDF.
            myDocument.Add(hw)
            myDocument.Close()

            Dim content As Byte() = myMemoryStream.ToArray()

            ' Write out PDF from memory stream.
            Using fs As FileStream = File.Create("eport_PDF.pdf")
                fs.Write(content, 0, CInt(content.Length))
            End Using
        End Using
End Sub
```

when i run this shows an error

System.InvalidCastException: Unable to cast object of type 'System.Web.UI.HtmlTextWriter' to type 'iTextSharp.text.IElement'.

on this line 
myDocument.Add(hw)

I use memory stream because of huge data when i use code without memory stream then shows an error Out of Memory exception so i use memory stream and now this shows different error

Comment: I've updated my answer. If you are a serious developer, you will stop using the word iTextSharp, you will upgrade to iText 7, and you will learn from tutorials instead of trying to reinvent the wheel.

Answer (score 1):

The `Add()` method in the `Document` object only accepts parameters that implement the `IElement` interface. You are passing an `HtmlTextWriter` object. That object is totally unrelated to iText. It is truly amazing that you would think this could work.

In this question, as in previous questions you posted (some of which are deleted), you refer to HTML. You were using `HTMLWorker` in [Add image using itextsharp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46191088/add-image-using-itextsharp) and the deleted question [Out Of Memory Exception error itext sharp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46196679/out-of-memory-exception-error-itext-sharp).

If you want to convert HTML to PDF, you should upgrade to iText 7 and use the [pdfHTML add-on](https://itextpdf.com/itext7/pdfHTML). Take a look at the tutorial to see how HTML to PDF conversion is done: https://developers.itextpdf.com/content/itext-7-converting-html-pdf-pdfhtml

In a comment to this answer however, you write: *I'm not exporting data in HTML to PDF.* OK, if that's true, then **why do you refer to HTML in your code?** That's very confusing.

Furthermore, you write *I create dummy grid-view in code and bind data in it.* Unfortunately, you don't give us any information about the format of that *dummy grid-view*. I assume, it's something you "invented" yourself, but if that's the case, how do you suppose that iText can magically understand the *dummy grid-view* you invented?

I started this answer by saying the the `Add()` method only accepts objects that implement the `IElement` interface. Since you are talking about a *grid*, it's probably interesting to use an iText table element. In iText 5, there's an object named `PdfPTable`; in iText 7, that object is simply named `Table`.

Many people with large data sets, create such a table object first, then add it to a `Document`. That's not always wise, because objects keep building up in memory, eventually resulting in an `OutOfMemoryException`. For large data sets, you should mark the table as a large element, and add the table gradually.

In iText 5, the code would look like this:

```
Document document = new Document();
FileStream stream = new FileStream(fileName, FileMode.Create);
var pdfWriter = PdfWriter.GetInstance(document, stream);
document.Open();
PdfPTable table = new PdfPTable(4);
table.Complete = false;
for (int i = 0; i < 1000000; i++) {
    PdfPCell cell = new PdfPCell(new Phrase(i.ToString()));
    table.AddCell(cell);
    if (i > 0 && i % 1000 == 0) {
        document.Add(table);
    }
}
table.Complete = true;
document.Add(table);
document.Close();
```

We're adding 1000000 cells to a table with 4 columns, but we add the table every 1000 cells (so every 250 rows). This means that the content is flushed from memory on a regular basis, thus avoiding an `OutOfMemoryException`.

Since you seem to be new at iText, do yourself a favor, and upgrade to using iText 7. iText 5 is in maintenance mode, which means that no new functionality will be added to that version. For instance: if at some point someone asks you to produce PDF 2.0 files (the PDF 2.0 spec was released a couple of months ago), you will have to throw all your iText 5 code away, and start anew, because only iText 7 will support PDF 2.0.

The large table functionality in iText 7, is discussed at the end of [chapter 5 of the tutorial](https://developers.itextpdf.com/content/itext-7-building-blocks/chapter-5-adding-abstractelement-objects-part-2):

```
PdfDocument pdf = new PdfDocument(new PdfWriter(dest));
Document document = new Document(pdf);
Table table = new Table(new[] {1f, 1f, 1f}, true);
table.AddHeaderCell("Table header 1");
table.AddHeaderCell("Table header 2");
table.AddHeaderCell("Table header 3");
table.AddFooterCell("Table footer 1");
table.AddFooterCell("Table footer 2");
table.AddFooterCell("Table footer 3");
document.Add(table);
for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
{
    table.AddCell($"Row {i + 1}; column 1");
    table.AddCell($"Row {i + 1}; column 2");
    table.AddCell($"Row {i + 1}; column 3");
    if (i % 50 == 0)
    {
        table.Flush();
    }
 }
 table.Complete();
 document.Close();
```

As you can see, the iText 7 code is much more intuitive. We create a table with 3 columns, and the second parameter (`true`) indicates that we will add a very large table. We add a header, we add a footer, and we add the table to the document. Then we add 1000 rows, but we `Flush()` the table every 50 rows. Flushing free memory, avoiding going out of memory. Once we're done, we `Complete()` the table.

**All of this is documented on the official web site!** There is no need for you to invent your own *grid view*. As you have found out, inventing your own grid view **cannot possibly work**.

**Also important:** you say iTextSharp, I say iText. We both mean the same thing: the PDF library produced by iText Group that can be used to create PDF documents from C# code. Only you are using the old name, whereas we try to avoid that name based on the advice of a Trademark who told us that there's a company named Sharp that doesn't appreciate other companies using the word Sharp in the context of brands that aren't related to their company. **So please stop saying that you're using iTextSharp; you're using iText!**

Comment: i am not exporting data in HTML to pdf.. i create dummy grid-view in code and bind data in it.. i directly export data in pdf on button click . ... if i am getting errors on that problem then i have post question stackoverflow this does  not mean you always down vote my question.. you may have more experience than me in development field this not mean you help others by down voting their question ... '

Comment: OK, so please explain me why you are using an `HtmlTextWriter` object. Why do you think that makes sense, and why do you assume that adding such an object to an iText `Document` instance would ever work? Where have you found anything that makes you believe that would work?

Comment: Downvoting questions is done to keep Stack Overflow clean. It's meant to discourage people who aren't serious, such as students using Stack Overflow to have others do their homework, or to keep lazy developers from asking people do their work for them. In your case, Stack Overflow is *not a substitute for an education*. Sure, you can learn many things from Stack Overflow, but Stack Overflow doesn't replace getting a computer sciences degree. For some reason, you don't understand the answers that are given. Either you are doing this out of malice, or you're not educated enough to understand.

Comment: @user123 I'm going to give you one more chance to learn. I'll update my answer, and if you don't (want to) understand that explanation, I'll give up on you. And I know from experience that if I give up on you, many other people will give up on you too.

Comment: dummy gridview means like this .... Dim GridView1 As New GridView i am not displaying that grid in page

Comment: `dest` is the parameter that defines the destination. It's the path where the PDF will be written. The fact that you ask proves that you didn't read the documentation. As for `GridView`: why would you spend memory creating a `GridView` when all you want is creating a table in PDF?

Comment: because i extract data from database through store procedure and bind data in gridview if i am using table then how i bind data in table?

Comment: There is no need to bind data. Please read the examples. In the tutorial, there are examples of databases (e.g. a database with all the Jekyll and Hyde movies, a database with all the American states, etc...). You just loop over the records, and you add the fields to the table as cells. It's a pity you don't read the documentation. Not reading the documentation costs tons of time, yours *and mine*.

Comment: And while you're at it, also read https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28161181/datagridview-to-pdf-with-itextsharp

Comment: in i text 5 or itext 7 examples?

Comment: If I were you, I'd read [Jump-start: chapter 1](https://developers.itextpdf.com/content/itext-7-jump-start-tutorial/chapter-1-introducing-basic-building-blocks), [Building Blocks: chapter 5](https://developers.itextpdf.com/content/itext-7-building-blocks/chapter-5-adding-abstractelement-objects-part-2), and [pdfHTML: chapter 4](https://developers.itextpdf.com/content/itext-7-converting-html-pdf-pdfhtml/chapter-4-creating-reports-using-pdfhtml).