# put data in table using iText

Tags: gridview, itext, export-to-pdf

First I put data in a dummmy gridview.
The data is obtained as the result of running a stored procedure on a database.
Then I try to add this data in table and try to export data to a pdf.

This is my code :

```
 Dim GridView1 As New GridView
    Dim pdfDoc As New iTextSharp.text.Document(iTextSharp.text.PageSize.A1, 10.0F, 10.0F, 10.0F, 0.0F)
    pdfDoc.Open()
    Dim pdfTable As New PdfPTable(3)
    For Each row As GridViewRow In GridView1.Rows
        Dim Val1 As String = row.Cells(0).Text
        Dim Val2 As String = row.Cells(1).Text
        Dim Val3 As String = row.Cells(2).Text
    Next
    pdfDoc.Add(pdfTable)
    pdfDoc.Close()
```

Now how do I add these values (val1, val2, val3) to the table and then export to pdf?

Any help please?

Answer (score 1):

This is some example iText code to work with tables.

```
Document document = new Document();
PdfWriter.getInstance(document, new FileOutputStream(dest));
document.open();
PdfPTable table = new PdfPTable(8);
for(int aw = 0; aw < 16; aw++){
    table.addCell("hi");
}
document.add(table);
document.close();
```

Comment: PS: This code was obtained by googling "iText how to create a table". The first link I get is the code example for iText7, the second link is the example for iText5.

Please consider putting **more effort** into solving the problem yourself in future.

Answer (score 1):

This is wrong:

```
Dim pdfTable As New PdfPTable(3)
For Each row As GridViewRow In GridView1.Rows
    Dim Val1 As String = row.Cells(0).Text
    Dim Val2 As String = row.Cells(1).Text
    Dim Val3 As String = row.Cells(2).Text
Next
```

It's wrong because you are merely defining three `string` values without doing anything with those values. Why would that ever work? Nothing happens in your code.

You need to add these `string` values to the `table` you have just defined.

```
Dim pdfTable As New PdfPTable(3)
For Each row As GridViewRow In GridView1.Rows
    pdfTable.Add(row.Cells(0).Text)
    pdfTable.Add(row.Cells(1).Text)
    pdfTable.Add(row.Cells(2).Text)
Next
```

Or rather, as explained in the answer to this question: [dataGridView to pdf with itextsharp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28161181/datagridview-to-pdf-with-itextsharp)

```
PdfPTable pdfTable= new PdfPTable(3);
foreach(DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView1.Rows) {
    foreach (DataGridViewCell celli in row.Cells) {
        pdfTable.AddCell(celli.Value.ToString());
    }
}
doc.Add(pdfTable);
```

You'll need to apply small changes to port this C# snippet to VBA code, but that shouldn't be a problem.

Also not that there are many variations on how to define the style of the cells of a `PdfPTable`. They are documented on the official web site.

Comment: i used itext7 ....